# dockerize NestJs project with build files only

Tags: docker, devops, nestjs

I want to dockerize my Nest API. I'm completely new to Docker so I created a fresh Nest project with the CLI. I created a .dockerignore and added every file that shouldn't live in the Docker image.

```
.git
.gitignore
coverage
LICENSE
README.md
CONTRIBUTING.md
docker-compose.yml
Dockerfile
node_modules/
.github
.vscode
npm-debug.log
npm-debug.log.*
```

Next I started with the Dockerfile.

```
FROM node:12.13-alpine As api

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

ADD . /usr/src/app

CMD npm start
```

I'm wondering why the image has a size of 321 MB. Does someone know how to improve this? I don't need fancy stuff for development and testing purposes etc. I just would like to get into Docker by starting with a small "clean" image to setup the docker-compose file for the TypeORM database support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need development and testing stuff, enhance project dependency installation in Dockerfile next way:

```
RUN npm install --production
```

Comment: thank you very much :) that lowered the size to 128MB. Not sure if this is still too much? I don't know the average size ...

Comment: and another question: The command `npm start` does not work anymore. That's because I only have some javascript files from the dist folder right? And when I want to use this command I have to create multistage builds for development and production?

Comment: Study your `package.json` and make sure that all dependencies required to application start contains in `dependencies` section but not in `devDependencies` or so on.

Comment: In simple approach you don't need to create multistage builds for your application, you have only two of them: development (in Typescript, it uses all dependencies) and prod/stage (it works in compiled JS and uses only dependencies from `dependencies` section)